# buildozer.spec, apk kivy file with folders crashing

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specifications.html

I keep making an apk file that crashes when opening it. I think it may have something to do with the app having three folders, buildozer not adding them and the app not finding the path for them.

I have 3 folders, one with the fonts used, other two empty but content is added when the app is used.

Is there a way to specify directories being added by buildozer or adding empty directories is already something that it does and I'm just clueless as to what the bug is?

[image]

Comment: Before you try to solve a problem, you should verify that you are working on the correct problem. Try examining the `logcat` to see what the problem is. Have a look at the [documentation](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#run-my-application).

Comment: Oh, so this works similar to a terminal giving the error message? I got several hours or work left but will play around with it at home tonight. Thanks!